# Wordpress Timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I am a back end dev for a WordPress website: https://westtechshipping.com.

The admin side is where the majority of our time is spent. We deal with packages ordered by our customers and deliver them. I have a system put in place where you upload a .csv file and the PHP function reads the contents of the .csv, then updates the data into the database, then sends out an email to our clients.

Over time we realized that we cannot do a .csv upload with more than 30 entries because we would get errors like this one

I took this image from google images because I cannot recreate the error at the moment due to the time of this post, but the error is similar.
[image]

We also sometimes get a page that says this

[image]

We've tried many things and are not sure what the issue is. These hiccups cause our data to be uploaded twice and multiple emails to be sent out to each client.
We have spoken to our server hosting, go daddy, and followed their recommendations of editing our user.ini accordingly.

This are our PHP settings from our user.ini

[image]

If this is an issue with the code, below is the current code for our .csv upload feature.

```
  if(isset($_POST["submitcsv"]))   // Upload Package Amount CSV File
    {
     $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen($file, "r");
     $c = 0;
     $c2 = 0;
     $row = 1;


     while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)// What?
     {
       $Name = $filesop[0];
       $AccID = $filesop[1];
       $Freight = $filesop[2];
       $Handling = $filesop[3];
       $Consolidation = $filesop[4];
       $Duty = $filesop[5];
       $VTax = $filesop[6];
       $Delivery = $filesop[7];
       $Insurance = $filesop[8];
       $Amount = $filesop[9];
       $Statuscsv = $filesop[10];
       $Pickup = $filesop[11];
       $trackingnumber =$filesop[12];



       if($row == 1)  { $row++; continue;}
       $num = count($filesop);

       //Separating First name
       $First_Name = substr($Name,0,strrpos($Name,' '));
       if(strrpos($Name, ' ')!== false){
         $First_Name = $First_Name;
       }else{
         $First_Name = $Name;
       }
       //Getting rid of blank costs

       if(empty($Freight)){$Freight = "0";}
       if(empty($Handling) ){$Handling = "0";}
       if(empty($Consolidation)){$Consolidation = "0";}
       if(empty($Duty) ){$Duty = "0";}
       if(empty($VTax) ){$VTax = "0";}
       if(empty($Delivery)){$Delivery = "0";}
       if(empty($Insurance)){$Insurance = "0";}
       if(empty($Amount)){$Amount = "0";}

       //$pkg = get_packages_query($trackingnumber);
       //$pkginv = get_invoices_by_trackingid($trackingnumber);
       $userID = explode('WT100',$AccID);
       $userdata = get_userdata( $userID[1] );
       $site_name = get_bloginfo('name');
       $messageinv = "                <style>
                     @media screen (max-width:768px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */
                               #packagetable{
                                 margin-left:20px;
                               }
                             }
                       </style>
            <div style='font-size:15px;'>
               <strong> Dear ".$First_Name."</strong>, <br><br>
               ".$site_name." has a package available for you. You can come in to collect during our working hours of Monday- Friday 8AM to 5PM and Saturdays 9AM to 1PM.
             </div>
              <br><br>
             <table id='packagetable' style='border:1px solid #8EAADB; margin-left:150px;'>
              <tr class ='invhead' style='background-color:#4472C4; color:white;'>
                <th>Charges</th>
                <th>Amount (EC)</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class ='2ndtr' >
                <td > Tracking Number </td>
                <td> ".$trackingnumber."</td>
              </tr>
               <tr class ='1str' style='background-color:#D9E2F3; '>
                 <td > Shipping Charge: </td>
                 <td> $".$Freight." </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class ='2ndtr' >
                 <td > Duty Charge: </td>
                 <td> $".$Duty."</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class ='1str' style='background-color:#D9E2F3; '>
                 <td > Handling Fee: </td>
                 <td> $".$Handling." </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class ='2ndtr' >
                 <td > Consolidation Fee: </td>
                 <td> $".$Consolidation." </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class ='1str' style='background-color:#D9E2F3; '>
                 <td > Delivery Fee: </td>
                 <td> $".$Delivery." </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class ='2ndtr' >
                 <td > <strong>Total Amount: </strong> </td>
                 <td><strong>$".$Amount."</strong> </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
             <div>
              <br><br>
              Thanks for using our service! We appreciate it.
               <br><br>
               Regards,<br>
               ".$site_name."
               <br>______________________________________________________<br><br>
               <strong>Call Us</strong><br><br>
               <strong>Rodney Bay</strong>: 458-9378    <strong>Castries</strong>: 451-9378    <strong>Vieux Fort</strong>: 454-9378
             </div>
             ";
    $messageinvadmin .=
    "                <style>
                  @media screen (max-width:768px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */
                            #packagetable{
                              margin-left:20px;
                            }
                          }
                    </style>
<div><strong>".$Name."</strong> with email address ".$userdata->data->user_email.", had an invoice update. <br><br>
      View the changes below
                </div>
          <br><br>
         <table id='packagetable' style='border:1px solid #8EAADB; margin-left:150px;'>
          <tr class ='invhead' style='background-color:#4472C4; color:white;'>
            <th>Charges</th>
            <th>Amount (EC)</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class ='2ndtr' >
            <td > Tracking Number </td>
            <td> ".$trackingnumber."</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class ='1str' style='background-color:#D9E2F3; '>
             <td > Shipping Charge: </td>
             <td> $".$Freight." </td>
           </tr>
           <tr class ='2ndtr' >
             <td > Duty Charge: </td>
             <td> $".$Duty."</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class ='1str' style='background-color:#D9E2F3; '>
             <td > Handling Fee: </td>
             <td> $".$Handling." </td>
           </tr>
           <tr class ='2ndtr' >
             <td > Consolidation Fee: </td>
             <td> $".$Consolidation." </td>
           </tr>
           <tr class ='1str' style='background-color:#D9E2F3; '>
             <td > Delivery Fee: </td>
             <td> $".$Delivery." </td>
           </tr>
           <tr class ='2ndtr' >
             <td > <strong>Total Amount: </strong> </td>
             <td><strong>$".$Amount."</strong> </td>
           </tr>
           <tr class ='1str' style='background-color:#D9E2F3; '>
             <td > Delivery Fee: </td>
             <td> $".$Delivery." </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
         _______________________________________________________
           <br><br>
            ";

          $closing =  "Regards,<br>
           ".$site_name."
           <br>______________________________________________________<br><br>
           <strong>Call Us</strong><br><br>
           <strong>Rodney Bay</strong>: 458-9378    <strong>Castries</strong>: 451-9378    <strong>Vieux Fort</strong>: 454-9378
         </div>
         ";

         $invtotalsql = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT invoice_total_charges FROM wp_xq4w067xaq_customer_invoice WHERE invoice_tracking_number = '$trackingnumber'"));
         $packstatsql = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT pms_status FROM wp_xq4w067xaq_package WHERE tracking_id = '$trackingnumber'"));

         if($Statuscsv == "Collected & Paid"){
           $Statuscsv = 5;
         }if($Statuscsv == "Available for Pick-Up"){
           $Statuscsv = 4;
         }if($Statuscsv == "Pending Invoice"){
           $Statuscsv = 3;
         }if($Statuscsv == "Paid"){
           $Statuscsv = 7;
         }if($Statuscsv == "Collected"){
           $Statuscsv = 9;
         }if($Statuscsv == "Shipped"){
           $Statuscsv = 2;
         }if($Statuscsv == "Received"){
           $Statuscsv = 1;
         }

             if($invtotalsql['invoice_total_charges'] !== $Amount OR $packstatsql['pms_status'] !== $Statuscsv){
                 send_email_pkg2($userdata->data->user_email, $messageinv, $site_name. ' Package Amount Update',$userdata->user_email_2,$userdata->user_email_3);
                 //send_email_pkg("shipping@westtg.com", $messageinvadmin, $site_name. "Package Amount update");
                 //send_email_pkg("5sp4lr9@gmail.com", $messageinvadmin, $site_name. "Invoices");
                 //send_email_pkg("5sp4lr9@gmail.com", $message3, $site_name. "Minimum Invoices");
            }



    $sql = "UPDATE wp_xq4w067xaq_package SET  pms_full_name='$Name',pms_status='$Statuscsv',pms_amount_owned='$Amount',pms_pickup='$Pickup' WHERE tracking_id='$trackingnumber'";
    mysql_query($sql);
          $c = $c + 1; // count number of package info updated
    $sql2 = "UPDATE wp_xq4w067xaq_customer_invoice SET invoice_shipping_charge='$Freight',invoice_handling_fee='$Handling',invoice_consolidation_fee='$Consolidation',invoice_duty_charge='$Duty',invoice_added_tax='$Vtax',invoice_delivery_fee='$Delivery',invoice_insurance='$Insurance',invoice_total_charges='$Amount' WHERE invoice_tracking_number='$trackingnumber'";
    mysql_query($sql2);
     $c2 = $c2 + 1;  // count number of invoices updated
     //update_invoice2();

}
$finaladmin = $messageinvadmin.$closing;
send_email_pkg("shipping@westtg.com", $finaladmin, $site_name. "Package Amount update");
// Success OR Error Message

       if($sql AND $sql2){
         echo "Your database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ." records in packages and ".$c2." records in invoices";
       }else{
         echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
       }

    }
```

Comment: what is max_input_vars value?

Comment: @vel it is set at 5000

Comment: set  max_execution_time 259200 and try

Comment: @vel what will this do?

Comment: in php.ini file I mean user.ini

Comment: @vel sorry i'm a bit confused. You want me to set max_execution_time to 259200 in the user.ini? Wouldn't that be catastrophic? What is a php.ini file?

Comment: you need to set in user.ini max_execution_time 259200 and try

Comment: @vel That didn't help. It just made the function take longer to run,

Comment: just comment this line and try. this mail function send_email_pkg2

Comment: @vel Okay without the emails going out, it ran without a hiccup with 87 entries. But we need emails to go out to each client.

Comment: for checking purpose comment this

Comment: i did comment it out.

Comment: @vel.... I said that i commented it out and it ran without a hicup with 87 entries. But we need emails to go out to each client. It will obviously go quickly without sending emails to 87 different people. The problem is how to make this go faster when updating information AND sending emails to 100+ people.

Comment: can you cehck your error_log

Comment: @vel the error_log is empty ;-;

Comment: Please check the error log in your cpanel

Comment: @vel we don't use cpanel. It's a managed wordpress hosting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128831/discussion-between-vel-and-peter-omiyi).

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.